# Swift generics: parameters cyclic dependencies resolution

Tags: swift, generics, circular-dependency

Sorry if that is not a concrete enough question, but can you suggest some methods to resolve generic parameters cyclic dependencies?

I have two types:

```
typealias RiskListPresenter = ListPresenter<RiskListViewController, ...> // <View: ListViewType (generic protocol)>

typealias RiskListViewController = SectionedListViewController<RiskListPresenter, ...> // <Presenter: ListPresenterType (generic protocol), ...>
```

The thing is, the Presenter needs to know the type of view to call methods to populate it, and the ViewController needs to know the type of the Presenter to instantiate it.

I've tried a dependency injection lib Dip, but I wasn't able to inject a generic type. Maybe there're some other techniques?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by removing the necessity to hold an actual type, replacing it with just a non-generic protocol.

So,

In `ListViewController` I hold the `presenter` as additional non-generic `protocol ListViewPresenterType`, that can do only what I want from it in here.

Initiated it as a required generic type from a generic method in `ListViewController`, conforming it to a generic protocol with all the necessary constraints.

```
func configure<Presenter: ListPresenterType>(..., presenterType: Presenter.Type, ...) where <all the necessary constraints>
{
    presenter  = Presenter(dispatcher: dispatcher, view: self as! Presenter.View)
    ...
}
```

Doing that, I was able to remove the `Presenter` from generic parameters in `ListViewController`.

A bit of a hack, but solves my issue and I need this `configure(...)` method anyway.

Still, that's not a real universal solution.